# Do i need OAuth for user authentication when designing the login for a mobile application?

Tags: php, api, security, mobile

I am trying to design a mobile application and I have some doubts about the path I need to take to implement the security.

Initially I thought OAuth2 is needed but after a bit of searching around the web I came to the conclusion (hopefully a correct one) that OAuth is used when I want users to authenticate into other applications using the credentials they used to create their account into my application.

So now my questions are:

1. is my understanding of the OAuth use case correct ?
2. if OAuth is not needed then passing the username and password to the api in order to create an account is enough?
3. how will I be able to access strictly the data that belongs to the user that is logged in when making an api request? (is this still sessions based, like logging in into a website ?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are not writing an oauth service

1. Yes , In the this case google,github etc they authenticate the user for you and
   redirect to the redirect url provided by you.
2. That would mean you are using basic auth [RFC 7616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616) and from what I've heard
   It is not as secure as bearer authentication [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).
3. That should be handled by your application an external oauth application will
   only do the initial authentication.[githubs oauth flow](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/)

Comment: I want to use Laravel Passport if OAuth2 is needed. Just to be clear, what I want is to create a login system where the user enters the credentials 1 time and that`s it (like 99% o mobile apps i know). So OAuth is the way to go here, correct?

Comment: Yeah laravel passport will provide you everything you need you can use the authtoken provided by laravel passport to access protected routes etc